# Redirect PHP URL with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-parameters

I have a website with several URLs like these:

```
domain.com/aff_link.php?id=363
```

and I need to redirect all of them to  a subfolder called "old"

like this:

```
domain.com/old/aff_link.php?id=363
```

those numbers at the end go from 2 up to 4 digits.

How can I do this in htaccess?

Currently I have this code

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(id)=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/.*)?$ http://domain.com/old? [R=301,L,NC]
```

but that redirects everthing to domain.com/old/
so as you can see I do not know what I am doing, please help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be pretty close ...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (aff_link.php) old/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Watch out for leading slashes depending on whether this is in a **VirtualHost** or **Directory** or **.htaccess** block.

Comment: that almost did it 
it redirects to :
    http://domain.com/old/(aff_link.php)?id=654
 
it writes this ( ) in the url

Comment: Sorry about that - removed the parentheses